# migration with two belongs_to for the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the next two models

```
class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
  # something ...
end

class CurrencyRate < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :rate
  belongs_to :currency_to_convert, :class_name => 'Currency'
  belongs_to :currency_converted, :class_name => 'Currency'
end
```

how should I create the migration for the CurrencyRate model, only with one field for the foreign key association or two fields?

I have been thinking in something like

```
class CreateCurrencyRates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :currency_rates do |t|
      t.integer :currency_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

but I'm not sure if works for a model with two belongs_to associations.

Comment: is converted an alias for to_convert?

Comment: "currency_converted" is the currency to the which I should apply a rate according to generate the value in "currency_converted" units

Comment: Do they both use the same foreign_key?

Comment: no, diferent foreign keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class CurrencyRate < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :rate
  belongs_to :currency_to_convert, :class_name => 'Currency', :foreign_key => 'currency_convert_id'
  belongs_to :currency_converted, :class_name => 'Currency', :foreign_key => 'currency_converted_id'
end

class CreateCurrencyRates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :currency_rates do |t|
      t.integer :currency_converted_id
      t.integer :currency_convert_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```